# how to count facebook "likes" and facebook "people talking about" of a page?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to count facebook "likes" and facebook "people talking about" metric of a page. I am making app for iPhone.
I want only the count number...
For example:- If I type url "www.facebook.com/coke", then it will show "Likes = 40,654,866" and "People talking about = 311,637" on a button click.

Comment: Have you tried going through example for integrating facebook platform for iPhone ? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Comment: Try posting the answer and accept it yourself, so in future other users who stumble upon this question can refer your answer.

Comment: ok. 
http://graph.facebook.com/Page_Name. For example, if you want the likes of Pepsi page, then just type "http://graph.facebook.com/pepsi" and u'll get the "likes" and "people talking about".

Comment: Great. But post it as an answer below, not a comment, then accept it yourself.

Comment: By accept i mean there will be a tick mark next to your answer. Use that.

Comment: thanx for the info... plz do guide me in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type:- www.graph.facebook.com/Page_Name. 
For example, if you want the likes of Pepsi page, then just type "graph.facebook.com/pepsi"; and u'll get the "likes" and "people talking about"